# Find Domain Instances that were updated today

Tags: grails

This sounds a painfully simple question but I'm having the hardest time finding how I can grab all the entries that were updated today.

```
def today = new Date()
def q = "from UserMapping as u where u.updateTime like :today"
def updated = UserMapping.findAll(q, [today: today])

java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.util.Date. Stacktrace follows:
```

I've tried about 10 other ways but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it using:

```
def today = new Date().clearTime()
def updated = UserMapping.findAllByUpdateTimeGreaterThanEquals(today)
```

If anyone has a more elegant method, please post it.

Comment: @JinzhaoWu that will modify the Date to represent the most recent midnight, so the finder returns objects modified at any time on the current day. I'd say that's pretty elegant as it stands. If you want modified within the last 24 hours then Groovy's TimeCategory allows you to say `1.day.ago` but I can't think of a better way to say "since midnight".